# Output of query formula appearing on next row

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I found this problem
"Output of query formula appearing on next row"

which is also asked here
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/110141252/output-of-query-formula-appearing-on-next-row?hl=en

but instead of addressing the problem (Why?) people just addressed the solution (a better formula).

Imagine you have a query formula (yellow cell), but the results appear on the row below.

[image]

Why?

Note: The data the "query" is checking has no empty rows.

Answer (score 1):

I really wanted to know "why?" and I found it.

The "query" has an optional parameter.

```
QUERY(data, query, [headers])
headers - [ OPTIONAL ] - The number of header rows at the top of data. If omitted or set to -1, the value is guessed based on the content of data.
```

[image]

Note: I know the first row doesn't look like a header (it is not), but the "query" does what you ask. If you ask for a header, it will assume there is one and display it.

If set to 0, no headers are displayed, if omitted, they are displayed.

But, If you have nested query like this

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(query(transpose(QUERY(A7:Q21, "SELECT * WHERE A = 'blah' ",1)) ,"select *  offset 5 ",0),"SELECT * LIMIT 2"))
```

Your results may appear on the row below your formula BECAUSE initially you were displaying headers, but then removed them (query above) with another query. In other words, your starting query has 2 rows of results (header + data), but those results are passed to another "query" that removes the "header". Therefore, what you see is an "empty row" that has no data (apparently), and some results on the row below.

[image]

To avoid that, just be consistent and specify "0" in the headers parameter for all the "query" queries, so your results will be on the row you expect, the one of the formula.

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(query(transpose(QUERY(A7:Q21, "SELECT * WHERE A = 'blah' ",0)) ,"select *  offset 5 ",0),"SELECT * LIMIT 2",0))
```

I hope it helps someone.